# UIKeyInput not available on iPad?

Tags: ios, uikeyinput

I have implemented the `UIKeyInput` protocol method `- (void)deleteBackward` but when the code is running on an iPad and I press the delete button on the keyboard it does not execute the method.

Is this protocol disabled on `ipad`?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue as well. Looks like iPad doesn't allow `UIView`s to simply implement `UIKeyInput`, you *must* implement `UITextInput` in order for a custom view to make the keyboard appear on iPad OS.